# Android JNI/NDK Application Context

Tags: android, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI to get the music library from Android with Qt. I call upon the following Java method (which is already implemented),

```
public String getArtists(Context context)
...
```

I need to be able to get the Context of the application in order for it to work.

If it helps, when I was using Java, the following code provided the correct context.

```
MainActivity.this
```

Could anybody be of assistance in this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you show the jni code you have tried?

Comment: Absolutely! http://pastebin.com/Kqjq3NWs This runs without errors.

Answer (score 3):

It will depend where you are making the call. Ideally you will cache the MainActivity pointer in C++.

One way to cache a pointer to use in a later JNI call is to add a native function in java such as `native void onCreateNative()` to you `MainActivity` class. In C++ you'll implement the method and cache the "thiz" pointer:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL com_package_MainActivity_onCreateNative(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{
    gCachedActivity = env->NewGlobalRef(thiz);
}
```

Now you can use `gCachedActivity` where you would have used `MainActivity.this`

```
env->CallObjectMethod(obj, s_getArtistsGetArtistsMethodID, gCachedActivity);
```

Of course replacing `obj` with the object you are calling the method on.

Lastly `onCreateNative()` should be called in the `onCreate()` method of `MainActivity`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do I have to add a function to the equivalent of MainActivity.java?

Comment: This is just one way to do it... but yes, add onCreateNative() to the MainActivity class

Comment: You should call the native method `onCreateNative(this)` to `onCreate()` callback of the **MainActivity** class.

Comment: @Alex Cohn You get the `this` pointer for free in native methods... if the method is added to a different class, yes, the MainActivity pointer will have to be passed in.

Comment: @krsteeve: right, the parameter is not necessary. But the point is that there is no built-in magic that will call onCreateNative() method; the developer should take care of this explicitly, doesn't she?

Comment: Hmm. I'll have to look into it more. I can't really edit the core Java files, only add my classes, as I'm running through Qt. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Another hint: sometimes, your Activity object will be destroyed and recreated by the system, while the app will still be running. To allow garbage collection of the obsolete object, you should delete the old global reference to MainActivity. You can call a native method that will call `env->DeleteGlobalRef(gCachedActivity)` from `MainActivity.onDestroy()`.

Comment: But there is one caveat: there is no guarantee that **onDestroy()** will be called every time an activity is destroyed. Sometimes, when the system resources are exhausted, there will be no callbacks except `onPause()`. Therefore, check that **gCachedActivity** is NULL, and if it isn't, call `env->DeleteGlobalRef(gCachedActivity)` in **onCreateNative()**, before you call `env->NewGlobalRef(thiz)`. And set `gCachedActivity = NULL` in `onDestroyNative()`.

Comment: @user2195592: you can add your class that will extend **MainActivity**. Will that help?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. @Alex, Did you mean extend MainActivity to get the ContentResolver from there? If so, I just tested it (with Java)- no avail.

Comment: @user2195592 extend `MainActivity`, lets call this new class `DerivedMainActivity`. Then in your application's manifest, replace `MainActivity` with `DerivedMainActivity`, then follow this solution in `DerivedMainActivity`

Comment: @user2195592 did you give this a try? how did it go?

Comment: I'm just going to wait for QtMobility to be released. Thanks for the help anyway!